# Problem while Open New Tab from Code Behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

hope you are all doing great!
I have a task to open a page in a new tab on a click of a button.
Let me show that,

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCreateQuestion" Text="Create Question" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnCreateQuestion_OnClick" OnClientClick="SetTarget();" />



   function SetTarget() {
            debugger;
            document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
        }

   protected void btnCreateQuestion_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 // other code ....
 switch (questionType) {
  case "Multiple Choice":
   Response.Cookies["options"].Value = optionNumber;
   Response.Redirect("~/Products/McQType.aspx?scode=" + subjectcodeid);
   break;
 }
}
```

Now this code is working as expected i.e the page is opening in a new tab...

now I have a grid and inside that grid I have a button which is responsible for the same i.e opening the page in a new tab..

```
//button located inside grid
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn" ID="btnEditQuestion" runat="server"
                                                            Style="padding-right: 10px; font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: -0.1px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important; font-weight: bold !important;"
                                                            OnClick="btnEditQuestion_OnClick"
                                                            OnClientClick="SetTarget();">
                                                            Edit Question
                                                            <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                        </asp:LinkButton> 


protected void btnEditQuestion_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 {
  case "Multiple Choice":
  Response.Redirect("~/Products/McQType.aspx?qid=" + questionId);
  break;
 }
}
```

Now the page is opening but not in a new tab, where it should open in a new tab..

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Web.UI;
    protected void btnEditQuestion_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     {
      case "Multiple Choice":
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "", 
     "window.open('~/Products/McQType.aspx?qid=" + questionId + "', '', '');", true);
      break;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro and I have done that already but I wanna know why my code is not working in the second case..       https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-ResponseRedirect-or-ServerTransfer-Open-New-Tab-from-Code-Behind.aspx